# Binning of Continous Predictor and Predicted Variables

Tags: r, data-mining, decision-trees

My problem has three categorical variables `C1`,`C2`, `C3` and one continous variable `X`, predicting a continuous outcome `Y`. I can visualize the problem with the following reproducible code (apology for the badly written code):

```
library(data.tree)
i = expand.grid(c("A","B"),c("C","D"),c("E","F"))
i = i[order(i[,1],i[,2],i[,3]),]
i[,4] = c(1:8)

t = expand.grid(c("A","B"),c("C","D"),c("E","F"),seq(0,1,0.1))
t = t[order(t[,1],t[,2],t[,3]),]
t = join(t,i, by = c("Var1","Var2","Var3"))
t$Var5 = runif(nrow(t))
t$pathString <- with(t, paste("Tree", Var1, Var2, Var3, V4, sep="/"))
plot_tree <- as.Node(t)

plot(plot_tree)
ggplot(data = t, aes(x=Var4, y=Var5)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(~V4)
```

The tree categorical variables show 8 possible path combinations:
[image]

And within each path there is a distribution of `Y` depending on a continuous variable `X`:
[image]
I would like to bin both the continuous `Y` and `X` variables such that I am left with a more concise decision tree. There is method to this madness as in my actual problem, some categorical paths will become insignificant due to no movement in the predicted `Y` beyond the established volatility threshold of 5%.

I can manually obtain bins by brute force, but is there a binning algorithm that supports binning of both predicted and predictor variables? I have looked at `smbinning` and my knowledge in this area of algorithms is limited. My actual problem has many categorical and continuous variables resulting in a more complex structure, but I would like to convert it to a decision tree result which will help me understand the significance and movement of variables better.